# C++ Static member variable - access between files

Tags: c++, static

I have declared a static member variable declared in one.h and initialized in  one.cpp as follows;

one.h

```
class one{
public static bool var1;
public void change();
}
```

one.cpp

```
#include 'one.h'
bool one::var1 = false;
void one::change()
{
one::var1 = true;
}
```

Change function is called via another thread.

Now in two.cpp I have the following code;

```
#include 'one.h'
class two{
public void fun()
{
//check the value of one::var1 after the change function has been called
}
}
```

Inside this function, the value I get for one::var1 is always false.

I read about static members are local to the defined file. I am uncertain of this behavior.

Why doesn't this change the value of the static variable?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] that replicates the problem. With some minor editing, the code you show should work fine.

Comment: file static is only defined in that file. Class static is completely different.

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? We don't do `public static bool ` here.

Comment: yes this is c++. Why wont you do public static bool here?

Comment: In C# or Java, you add `public` before each member, but in C++ you only do that once before a group of members with same visibility. And you **have to** add colon after the keyword, like this: `public:`. And you're missing semicolons after classes, which is another Java-ism.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am using the logic in an application where CEF is being used. I wonder if the inter process communication feature of CEF has anything to do with this. CEF is the chromium embedded framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the variable from multiple threads I would recommend you use `static std::atomic<bool> var1;`

Some times the compiler might cache the value.